# Como hacer Template con Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html5, template, vue.js

No logro hacer este ejemplo en mi pc local [ejemplo Template](http://www.webpackbin.com/4ydPUEnMz), en si quiero crear un template en un archivo aparte donde pueda llamarlo y usarlo en cualquier parte de mi html, con el fin de simplificar codigo, pero no logro hacerlo porque no logro identificar si me faltan otros CDN o que otra cosa debo hacer.

**Este es el HTML**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app></app>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Este el archivo main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

**Este es el Template App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Creaste el proyecto con vue-cli? Y si lo hiciste, lo ejecutas con `npm run dev`?

Comment: Hola Javier, gracias por responder, si instalo vue-cli, por lo que entiendo, instalaría una serie de librerías y dependencias que a la final no sabría cual es la que realmente realiza la acción de lo que estoy buscando.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si puede usar este `el: 'body',` en esta manera. Creo que si pone un `<body id="body">` y cambia a `el: '#body',` talvez sera funca. Si no, hay un plugin para Chrome Devtools que es muy util.

(Perdon mi español)

Comment: Hola user28490, realice tu sugerencia y no funciono. en cuanto al español se entiende!. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar archivos .vue debes usar un loader con webpack o algún otro bundler.
Con el [cli de vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/) puedes generar un un proyecto que ya implementa toda la configuración de webpack necesaria.